# Proof that a graph with at most $n+2$ edges is planar

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Show that a connected, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ with $n$ vertices and at most $n+2$ edges is planar.
The only theorem I'm aware of to show that a graph is planar or not planar is kuratowskis theorem. So I have to show that a given graph with at most $n+2$ edges can't contain a subdivision that is $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.

My observations:

- a connected graph must contain at least $n-1$ edges. Otherwise the graph is not completely connected.
- $K_{3,3}$ has 6 vertices and each vertex has degree of 3.
- Similarly $K_5$ has 5 vertices and each vertex has degree of 5.

My idea: Show that a graph with at most $n+2$ edges does not contain 5 vertices with degree of 5 AND not 6 vertices with a degree of 3.
Then it is not possible for the graph to contain either $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ as subdivision.

And from here I'm not sure on how to combine my observations into a proof. Do you have a hint for me here?

Comment: You need to be a bit more careful: Kuratowski's Theorem is about *subdivisions*, not subgraphs. Your approach will also not work - for example, you can have a tree with many high degree vertices.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez you're right. I edited my post.
Hmm... Maybe a proof by contradiction might work. $K_5$ has 5 vertices and 10 edges. So to get m=n+2 we must add more vertices, but each additional vertex adds another edge, hence we always have to much edges...Therefore it cannot contain the $K_5$ as subdivision and therefore must be planar

Comment: See this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211715/lower-bounds-on-the-number-of-edges-in-a-nonplanar-graph. A. Schulz's   answer seems to be the right idea, but it is a bit sketchy

Answer (score 4):

I propose this solution without Kuratowski's theorem.

1. If a graph $G'$ is obtained from a graph $G$ by removing a vertex of degree $1$ or by smoothing a vertex of degree $2$, then $G$ is planar if and only if $G'$ is planar and $|E(G')|-|V(G')|=|E(G)|-|V(G)|$.
2. It follows from 1 that we can assume that the degree of each vertex of graph $G$ is at least $3$.
3. By the handshaking lemma we obtain
   $$
   2(n+2)=\sum_{v\in G} \deg(v)\geq 3n\Rightarrow n\leq 4.
   $$
   Since any graph on four vertices is planar, it follows that graph $G$ is planar.

**Note.**
Not everything is as beautiful as we would like it to be.
If at any step as a result of smoothing a vertex of degree $2$ we get a graph with multiple edges, then we can replace all edges connecting these two vertices with a single edge. For the new graph $G'$ we get
$|E(G')|-|V(G')|<2$ and still planarity $G$ is equivalent to planarity $G'$. 
By the way, in this case it may happen that after multiple removal of all vertices of degree 1 and smoothing of vertices of degree 2 followed by replacement of parallel edges by a single edge we get $|V(G)|=1$ and then of course the 3th step is not needed.

**Note 2.**
It is possible that someone does not like the process of smoothing the vertices of degree 2.
Or the author of the question insists on going that way - this seems to me the right way, although here you have to use Kuratowski's theorem. In this case you can also reason this way.

Consistently removing vertices of degree $1$ (if necessary) we can assume that degrees of all vertices of graph $G$ are at least $2$.

If there are $k_d$ vertices of degree $d=2,3,4\ldots$, then $k_2+k_3+k_4+\ldots=n$ and by the handshaking lemma
$$
2(n+2)=\sum_{v\in G}\deg(v)=\sum_{d\geq2} k_d\cdot d=2n+\sum_{d\geq3} k_d(d-2)
$$
Since $k_3+2k_4+3k_5+4k_6=4$, there are no vertices of degree greater than 6 and
one of the following cases takes place:

| - | $k_3$ | $k_4$ | $k_5$ | $k_6$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | $0$ | $0$ | $0$ | $1$ |
| 2. | $1$ | $0$ | $1$ | $0$ |
| 3. | $0$ | $2$ | $0$ | $0$ |
| 4. | $2$ | $1$ | $0$ | $0$ |
| 5. | $4$ | $0$ | $0$ | $0$ |

The following is clear.

Comment: An elegant proof! Two views for generalizing the problem can be explored, one being k-plane graphs and the other being crossing numbers.  I will be present a new problem.

Comment: See this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4637623/lower-bound-on-the-number-of-edges-in-a-non-k-planar-graph

Comment: Should the equation in the text be changed to an inequality sign?$$
\sum_{d\geq2} k_d\cdot d = 2n+\sum_{d\geq3} k_d(d-2)
$$  or $$\sum_{d\geq2} k_d\cdot d \ge 2n+\sum_{d\geq3} k_d(d-2)?
$$

Comment: @licheng,
I didn't understand your question, but I added one equality to my answer just in case.

Comment: It seems that in your equality, the number of $2$-degree vertices is exactly $n$, and I don't understand why.

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood the equality.

Comment: @licheng, I apologize. Just added the promised equality to my answer.