# Lower bound on the number of edges in a non-$k$-planar graph.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, extremal-graph-theory

**Just for fun!**

This problem is a generalization of the question I came across in the following post:

- [Proof that a graph with at most n+2 edges is planar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4637116/proof-that-a-graph-with-at-most-n2-edges-is-planar)

That means that  every non-planar graph (non-1-planar graph) has at least $n+3$ edges.

> A $k$ -planar graph is a graph that can be drawn in the Euclidean
> plane in such a way that each edge has at most $k$ crossing point,
> where it crosses other edges. Clearly, $k$-planar graphs are
> one of the most natural generalizations of planar graphs.

Hence, I propose the following similar problem: **What is the lower bound on the number of edges in a non $k$-planar graph?**

Upon closer examination of the proof of *kabenyuk*, it has been determined that the presence or absence of 2-degree vertices and 1-degree vertices does not affect the planarity of the graph.  At this point, we note that 2-degree vertices do have an impact on $k$-planarity when $k\ge 1$.

For exmaple, $K_7$ is not 1-planar, but when we insert 2-degree vertices, it can be changed a 1-planar graph.

[image]

**A starting problem**:

Can we construct infinitely many non-1-planar (connected) graphs with $n+3$ edges?

Comment: Why are you keeping $n+3$? Are there *any* non-$1$-planar graphs with $n$ vertices and $n+3$ edges?

Comment: The question seems very interesting. It is a bit disturbing that $k$-planarity is not preserved when subdividing the graph.
In this sense, $1$-planar graphs are more malleable. It seems to me that every non-$1$-planar graph has at least n+8 edges (or $n+10$). But the proof needs to be modified a bit from the case of non-planar graphs. It is possible that I am wrong.

Comment: @ Misha Lavrov It's a start, and I'm increasingly convinced it doesn't exist. (I am thinking about why)

Comment: @kabenyuk If we continue to follow your method, at this point we keep removing vertices of leaves(see Misha Lavrov‘s answer) , and when $m=n+10$ the situation seems to become unusually numerous, with a total of 627 solutions for this equation  $k_3+2k_4+3k_5+4k_6+\cdots +20k_{20}=20$. One of the cases is that  $k=20$. So we can ask whether there are 3-regular non-1-planar graphs with 20 vertices.

Comment: Sorry. My analysis above seems incorrect. The 2-degree vertexices have not been taken into account, nor is it a graph with 20 vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than subdivide edges, another way to get bigger graphs while keeping the difference $|E|-|V|$ the same, and not affecting $k$-planarity, is to add leaf vertices. Most simply, just take a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, and add a path with $t$ new vertices and $t$ new edges from one of its vertices; the result has $n+t$ vertices and $m+t$ edges, and the new graph is $k$-planar if and only if the original graph was.

I do not think we will find infinitely many examples of non-$1$-planar graphs with $n$ vertices and $n+3$ edges, because I do not think we will find any. The question is: what is the best difference between edge and vertex count we can achieve?

I found many examples of non-$1$-planar graphs with $n$ vertices and $n+11$ edges. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-planar_graph), $K_{3,7}$ (with $10$ vertices and $21$ edges), $K_{4,5}$ (with $9$ vertices and $20$ edges), $K_{1,3,4}$ (with $8$ vertices and $19$ edges), and $K_{1,1,1,1,3}$ (with $7$ vertices and $18$ edges) are not $1$-planar. This ultimately comes from [1-planarity of complete multipartite graphs](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dam.2011.11.014) by Czap and Hudák. Also, [Minimal non-$1$-planar graphs](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2007.04.009) by Korzhik points out that $K_{1,1,1,1,3} = K_7 - K_3$ is a minimal non-$1$-planar graph, and that subdividing one of the edges between its degree-$6$ vertices gives another minimal non-$1$-planar graph (with $8$ vertices and $19$ edges).

Of course, we can use the path-adding technique to construct infinitely many non-$1$-planar graphs with $n$ vertices and $n+11$ edges. I'm pointing out that there's a bunch of $n+11$ examples because I think it's evidence that we can't reach $n+10$; if we hit the same wall from many different directions, we can suspect that the wall is everywhere. (But it's not very *strong* evidence.)

Comment: It is interesting. I feel like the question is already in a research-level.